# HikariCP: MySQL Communications link failure. The last packet successfully received from the server was 0 milliseconds ago

Tags: mysql, hikaricp

we run an application that connects to MySQL on a remote server and saw a Communications Link Failure in our application logs. The logs also say that

> The last packet successfully received from the server was 0
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   0 milliseconds ago.

so we think this exception did not happen because of a stale connection that was killed by the server. Here is the complete stack trace:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 0 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor19.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:93)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:133)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:149)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.readPacket(MysqlaProtocol.java:446)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.checkErrorPacket(MysqlaProtocol.java:637)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.sendCommand(MysqlaProtocol.java:581)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlaProtocol.java:865)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlaSession.java:452)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2036)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.cj.core.io.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:60)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:48)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:51)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.readPacket(MysqlaProtocol.java:440)
```

we are pretty clueless how to go about debugging this partially because we don't know any steps to repro this error consistently. we are using default settings of HikariCP. Our mysql admin told us they do kill connections that have been idle for more than 5 minutes, but from above it looks like our connection was not idle for that long.

Our admin also claims there was no server restart when the exception occurred. How is a client supposed to handle server restarts or network breakdowns btw? Does the client need to implement retry logic itself or does it come out of the box? Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Set your idleTimeout to 30 seconds less than the server-side idle timeout.  Find out if there is a server-side maximum connection lifetime, and if so set maxLifetime to that value (does not need to be 30 seconds less).

Comment: @brettw the error message says the last packet send and received from the server was 0 milliseconds ago. so we don't think this exception happened as a result of connection getting killed because it was idle for very long. similarly for the connection lifetime, it comes into play once a connection is closed and returned to the pool. whereas our error message seems to suggest a communications like failure happened when a connection was in active use.

Comment: @morpheus did you find any solution?

Comment: @morpheus bump. any solution?